# Can Stratolaunch land with the rocket still attached?

Tags: landing, abort, emergency, stratolaunch

Is the Stratolaunch plane able to land with the rocket still attached, if a malfunction is detected – and the plane has to return without having launched its load?

Is there a known emergency scenario for the already flying Stargazer?  (Stargazer is the [Lockheed L-1011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargazer_(aircraft)) that Pegasus launches from today)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stargazer can definitely land with the rocket still attached.  In fact Pegasus is usually loaded to Stargazer (with or without payload) at Vandenberg and then ferried to its actual launch site (CCAFS, Wallops, Kwaj, etc.)  Stargazer is also able to abort a launch and return to the landing strip if there is anything wrong with the system.  I believe this has happened before, but would have to go digging through historical articles to find information on what mission(s) it happened on.

I expect Strato would be the same.  We have a tendency to discover off-nominal readings in a rocket just before launch.  It would be a pity if every time that happened, the rocket and its payload had to be ditched.

Comment: Makes sense, if it can take off with a fully loaded rocket on board it should be able to land.

Comment: That reasoning is actually invalid. For example, when airliners dump fuel or circle around to burn off fuel, that is precisely because they can *not* land with the same weight they can take off. The maximum takeoff weight is usually significantly higher than the maximum landing weight. Note: I am not saying that this is true for Stargazer and/or Stratolaunch, I just want to point out that your reasoning "They can take off, therefore they must be able to land" may not be valid.

Comment: I agree with @JörgWMittag - just because it can take off doesn't mean it can land with it.  In the case of Pegasus, and I'm assuming Strato, the reason is much more powerful - I have a $$$M satellite hanging from the belly.  I'm not going to ditch unless it is an absolute need.

Comment: @Tim For starters, in the specs of most commercial transport-category aircraft. The Maximum Landing Weight is usually significantly less than the Maximum Take-Off Weight on long-haul aircraft. However, the difference for narrow-body aircraft is usually pretty small. The reason for the discrepancy is that a significant amount of weight and cost can be saved by designing the land gear and brakes for the smaller loads of a lighter landing aircraft than for a heavier departing one. Landing gear loading and brake heating isn't much of a concern on takeoff.

Comment: @Tim It's in GdD's comment, not in the answer.

Comment: @reirab I see - my confusion was because Jorg did not reply to the comment.

Comment: @reirab I see - my confusion was because Jorg did not reply to the comment.

Comment: @Carlos N: Your answer sounds reasonable. Just being curious: Why do you know? Are you involved in operations like that?

Comment: @peter I work in the industry. I’m fairly familiar with launch and satellite ops. For Pegasus that information is public.

Comment: @Carlos N: Stargazer launches (mostly) a solid propellant rocket. I assume that the stratolaunch rockets will be propelled by liquid engines as the comapany hired Jeff Thornburg, former vice president of propulsion at SpaceX. Does that make a (safety-)difference during the landing?

Comment: @Peter - I would expect liquids would make a difference.  But I have never looked into it. Virgin is also using a liquid.   Business logic dictates, however, that you better figure how to land with a full rocket.  You can't just dump a cargo of expensive spice at the first sight of an Imperial cruiser.